# Angularjs calling java functions

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have one simple web application in JAVA and angularjs. Where users can add persons to app and remove them from mongo database.

My problem is, I don't know exactly how angular communicates with java and calls Java functions. For example if i want to delete a person from my database after a button click.

here's some code

**persons.html**

```
<a for-authenticated ng-click="remove(s.id)" href=""> <i
     class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</a>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('conferenceApplication', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'angularFileUpload',
'ngQuickDate']);


 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
           templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
           controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .when('/speakers', {
          templateUrl: '/partials/person-list.html',
          controller: 'PersonListCtrl'
      })
});
app.controller('PersonListCtrl', function ($scope,$http, $modal, $log, $route, PersonService) {
$scope.remove = function(id) {
    var deletedPerson = id ? PersonService.remove(id, function(resp){
        deletedPerson = resp;
    }) : {};
};
}
```

**PersonService.js**

```
app.service('PersonService', function ($log, $upload, PersonResource) {
this.getById = function (id, callback) {
    return PersonResource.get({personId: id}, callback);
};
this.remove = function(id, callback) {
    return PersonResource.deleteObject({PersonId: id}, callback);
}
}
```

**PersonResource.js**

```
app.factory('PersonResource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('rest/person/:personId',
    {
        personId: '@personId'
    },
    {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' }
    })
```

});

also i have a java class where i want to delete this person from database

**PersonResource.java**

```
@Controller
 @RequestMapping("/person")
   public class PersonResource {

     @Autowired
     private PersonService personService;

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
     public ResponseEntity<Person> deleteObject(@RequestBody Person id) {
        Person person = personService.findById(id);
        personService.deleteObject(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(person, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
     }
   }
```

**PersonRepository**

```
  @Override
  public void deleteObject(String id) {
      getTemplate().remove(new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(id)), Person.class);
  }
```

the getTemplate() returns MongoTemplate.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong to get my entry deleted from database ?

Comment: Well RESTful webservices are used to talk to the Java backend. You should study that (JAX-RS is the name of the Java API) and get familiar with it. But you forgot to actually mention what your problem is. You get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: with that code i have an error  Error: SpeakerResource.deleteObject is not a function.

Comment: So a Javascript error. You didn't post the SpeakerResource javascript code though. At this point I have to assume the browser is not lying and the function simply does not exist.

Comment: sry edited that. i feel dumb now, but how i could possibly implement that function to tell java to delete that person?

Comment: I would suggest to look at the docs for Angular $resource here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource. There is also the doc on how to create a custom method, in case you need to implement one.

Comment: Note that $resource already has a default `delete` method

Answer (score 2):

So when using GET method usual we fetch some data, if we want to send some data to server (ex. an id for person to be deleted) we use POST method or DELETE method, in my example I'll use POST method for simplification. Angular and java communicate thru RESTFUL services (JAX-RS), You cant call java function in angular js or vice verse. I'll show simple example of fetching data and sending data (fetch all persons, delete person with given id).

Here is an example where You can start learning from:

**Java Person Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/person")
public class PersonController{

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(final PersonService personService) {
        this.personService= personService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return personService.getPersons();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{personId}", method = { RequestMethod.POST})
    @ResponseBody
    public HttpStatus deletePerson(@PathVariable final long personId) {
        return personService.deletePerson(personId);
    }
}
```

**Java Person Service**

```
public class PersonService{

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonService(final PersonRepository personRepository) {
       this.personRepository= personRepository;
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return personRepository.findAll();;
    }

   public HttpStatus deletePerson(final long id) {
       if (id > 0) {
           personRepository.delete(id);
           return HttpStatus.OK;
       } else {
           return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
       }
   }
}
```

**Java Person Repository**

```
public interface PersonRepository{
      public void delete(int personId);

      public List<Person> findAll();
}
```

**Angular app.js**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('personApp',[]);

    app.controller('personCtrl',function($scope,$http){

        $scope.getPersons = function(){
            $http.get('person/').success(function(response){
                $scope.allPersons = response.data;
            }).error(function(){
               //handle error
            })
        };

        $scope.deletePerson = function(personId){
            $http.delete('person/'+personId).success(function(response){
                $scope.deleteResponseStatus = response.status;
            }).error(function(){
               //handle error
            })
        }
    })
})();
```

**Html**

```
<html ng-app="personApp">
   <body ng-controller=""personCtr>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="getPersons()"/>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="deletePerson(somePersonIdFromTableOrSomething)"
   </body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help, not tested but generally that is the flow..send request to controller with person id, find it in database and delete it

Comment: any help on this                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386406/no-referrer-when-downgrade-error-integrating-java-service

Answer (score 0):

You need to attack the issues individually. Try testing your rest service alone. Use POSTMAN or any other REST Client (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) and test if the service is behaving accordingly. Only when that's successful, check on the Javascript client (AngularJS code) and see if the request (headers, params and body) is the same as the one generated by the REST client.

Answer (score 0):

you can call java method or service in angularjs controller this way:

```
app.controller('personCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.personList = [];
    $scope.typelistload = function() {
        $http.get(
            'http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate/Person/getPersonList'
        ).success(function(data) {
            $scope.personList = data;
        }).error(function() {
            ngToast.danger( "Some problem in Listing:");
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: @SiddhartRathi - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386406/no-referrer-when-downgrade-error-integrating-java-service                                              Any help on my questions, somewhat similar to what u answeres